# Pin folders in Windows 8.1 taskbar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, windows-8.1

In Windows 8 I loved the ability to pin any folder to taskbar. (with a workaround)

Now, it looks like they broke the way it works.

I have those problems:

1. When I click a "pinned" folder in 8.1, it takes like 3 seconds to the Explorer window to open
2. Opening a "pinned" folder, will create another icon on taskbar (like it's just a launcher)
3. When I middle-click the folder window on the taskbar, a "this computer" window opens, not a duplicate of my pinned folder.

There's another way to pin folders to the taskbar that works as before?

This really bugs me, unfortunately it's not possible to "uninstall" 8.1, since it's treated as a whole new OS, not a service pack.

Answer (score 3):

I came across that problem too.
Here's a solution:

```
 1. Pin File Explorer to taskbar
 2. Create a standart shortcut to your folder on Desktop.
 3. Move newly created shortcut to C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Quick Launch/User Pinned/TaskBar
 4. Remove "File Explorer" shortcut
 5. Name your shourtcut "File Explorer"
```

This is like replacing proper File Explorer shortcut with your folder shortcut.

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try it later

Comment: It says "can't find the element, delete?"